# codeigniter href link on server

Tags: php, function, .htaccess, codeigniter, href

I am new for codeigniter framework. I am having problem href link in code. It work well in localhost but not on server. All pages of my site working well. The form attribute action trigger working but below mention href link not work and not call to signup function in controller. Kindly suggest the way forward.

> 1.Href link which call "signup ()" - NOT WORKING

```
<a href="<?= base_url();?>index.php/login/signup" class="btn btn-success"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span> Add Student Account</a>
```

> 2.Form attribute "action" which calls "admin_validate_credentials()" - working well

```
<form action='<?= base_url();?>index.php/login/admin_validate_credentials' method="post" name="login-form" id="login-form" role="form" autocomplete="off">
```

Comment: if by "not working" you mean 404 the obvious question is does you login controller have a method called signup? it would also be helpful to share relevant parts of your login controller

Answer (score 0):

**Hope this will help you :**

First set `base url` in your `config.php` like this :

```
// change testing with your folder name
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/testing/';
```

and then use `site_url` in your anchor like this :

***Note*** : make sure your `Login controller` should have `signup` method

```
<a href="<?=site_url('login/signup');?>" class="btn btn-success">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span> Add Student Account
</a>
```

Comment: did u check my answer ?is it helpful?

Comment: pls always response to the answers by giving some comments or ,if it helps you, by marking it as green and upvoting, it is the best way to thanks all the programmers